# 404 not found error on localhost .php file

Tags: php, linux, localhost, http-status-code-404, lamp

I'm just starting to learn php programing and I'm having this frustrating problem that does not let me to go on.

I just set up LAMP server on my linux mint with default settings on localhost. Problem is that when I create .php file in var/www browser can not find it and shows 404 not found message.
When I created info file to view php info everything worked fine,

```
<?php info(); ?>
```

when creating new random php file in same location then the error comes up.

I lost whole day looking for an answer but not luck.

Comment: You should check if PHP are already installed correctly first .  and your web server can detect it . you should check you Apache Nginx etc configuration .

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reinstall the LAMP and it gave me the same result.

Then I found a post that suggested, default location for .php files might be in /var/www/html and not /var/www, so I tried that and it worked.
Hope somebody will find this helpful.

Comment: Good so it miss configuration in LAMP setting ....
always document root folder  are tricky . this is first thing you should check out after install LAMP .

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect function.

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: ^^ error he getting . from question title the Error 404 comes from web server when it's no detect webserver document root or some missing configuration . his error not related to php it's related to Apache or Nginx or whatever webserver he use

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for replies, I'm using apache server. http://localhost is working

Comment: Can you paste content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on windows, but the issue might be the same - just use a root directory which doesn't have whitespaces. ~~ hope it helps